# Typescript: why does this trivial generic function not behave like its non-generic equivalent?

Tags: typescript

```
type Greeting = { name: "Hello" } | { name: "Hi!" };

export function foo(name_of_greeting: Greeting["name"]): Greeting {
  return { name: name_of_greeting };
}

export function bar<N extends Greeting["name"]>(name_of_greeting: N): Greeting {
  return { name: name_of_greeting };
}
```

`foo` typechecks fine, but `bar` produces the following error:

> Type '{ name: N; }' is not assignable to type 'Greeting'.

Naively, I would expect `bar` to be completely equivalent to `foo`. Why does TypeScript disagree?

Comment: If you'll read the full error message you'll see exactly why. TLDR `type Greeting = { name: "Hello" | "Hi!" }` is not equivalent to above definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The TypeScript compiler does not *in general* break object types with union-typed properties into unions of object types with non-union properties.  Before TypeScript 3.5 this was not done *at all* ([both functions fail in TS3.3](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.3.3#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gThCwCWA7A5lAvFA3lVAQwFsIAuKAIgAkIAbOge0qgF8oAfPAk8q65AEIWrANwBYAFBSIADzCM4wKADMArqgDGKRqlWNGACiKkA+oxWn0CJGnQV4iFBgDalExEoBdAJQObzpi4UlBQCMBqcHr4HhQe5pbWTnZsEpKsUjLyisrqWjp6AEaEcAA8AHJQcsAQqAAmAM6wAXZuHt4AfMa8CVYtGBTlfs3JGHghYUiR0TykcT0WfaOYYlIZ0pJAA)).  TypeScript 3.5 introduced ["smarter" union type checking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#smarter-union-type-checking) in which some *concrete* unions of properties are sometimes checked this way... and your `foo()` function compiles successfully.

Theoretically one could always break objects-of-unions into unions-of-objects: for example, `{a: string|number; b: boolean; c: object | null}` could be exploded into `{a: string, b: true, c: object} | {a: string, b: true, c: null} | {a: string, b: false, c: object} | {a: string, b: false, c: null} | {a: number, b: true, c: object} | {a: number, b: true, c: null} | {a: number, b: false, c: object} | {a: number, b: false, c: null}`).  But, this would likely be a huge performance penalty and would only be beneficial in some use cases.

I assume it would be even more difficult/expensive to manipulate union-typed properties when the type is generic, where `{a: T}` where `T extends 0 | 1` would be some generic type `U extends {a: never} | {a: 0} | {a: 1}`.  So the language hasn't done it.  This could be considered either 
[intentional](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12052) or a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8289#issuecomment-214554425) of TypeScript.

---

Anyway, my workaround here would be to widen the returned value in `bar()` to a concrete type that the compiler *will* correctly check, like this:

```
export function bar<N extends Greeting["name"]>(name_of_greeting: N): Greeting {
  const concreteGreeting: { name: "Hello" | "Hi!" } = {
    name: name_of_greeting
  };
  return concreteGreeting;
}
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBA4gThCwCWA7A5lAvFA3lVAQwFsIAuKAIgAkIAbOge0qgF8oAfPAk8q65AEIWrANwBYAFBSIADzCM4wKADMArqgDGKRqlWNGACiKkA+oxWn0CJGnQV4iFBgDalExEoBdAJQObzpi4UlBQCMBqcHr4HhQe5pbWTnZsEpKsUjLyisrqWjp6AEaEcAA8AHJQcsAQqAAmAM6wAXZuHt4AfMa8CVYtGBTlfs3JGHghUJq6DcpTWuEQjrYD3LH89EwsXDRCItjjkqGha-EWfaPoE2IT4ZF6c5oLS4FpGZJAA)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at what the compiler shows when you hover over `N` - In your generic function, when you write `N extends Greeting["name"]` you're really saying `N extends "Hello" | "Hi!"`.

This means that the return value of `bar` is in fact of type `{ name: "Hello" | "Hi!" }`, and not `Greeting`.

Though this is similar to the type you've declared for Greeting, these are not in fact equivalent; hence the type error you're encountering.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! It indeed explains the error message, but it does not explain why the non-generic function does work.